# ZK showBusy called before long operation, but it is showed after it

Tags: java, zk

Using Zk 6.5.11CE.

In a modal window I got a button which clicked send an email. It is a long operation, and in waiting time I want to use Clients.showBusy to block the user to click/modify my modal window.

Here's the ZUL

```
<window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('viewmodel.EventView')">
    ...fill the form...
    <button label="SEND" onClick="@command('send')" autodisable="self" />
</window>
```

Here's Java **EventView.java**

```
@Command
@NotifyChange("*")
public void send() {
    Clients.showBusy(winFather.getModalWin(), "Please wait...");
    // ... do something ...
    sendMail(); // it takes 2/3 seconds
    Clients.clearBusy(winFather.getWinEvent());
}
```

Where winFather is the win (my *home page*) that called the modal window and getModalWin() get the modal window, in which i got the showBusy problem. Hope it is clear :)

However, i'm searching the web and found something interesting [here](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/83834/showbusy-delay-inside-of-a-listener/) and [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Long_Operations/Use_Echo_Events). So I got I have to use Echo Events.

For those had not clicked links:

```
<window id="w" width="200px" title="Test echoEvent" border="normal">
  <attribute name="onLater">
    doLongOperation(); //take long to execute
    Clients.clearBusy(); //remove the busy message
  </attribute>
  <button label="Echo Event">
    <attribute name="onClick">
      Clients.showBusy("Execute..."); //show a busy message to user
      Events.echoEvent("onLater", w, null); //echo an event back
    </attribute>
  </button>
</window>
```

Question(s):

1. is Echo Events the only chance to resolve the problem, or maybe I forgot to do something to make showBusy properly works?
2. because I really don't want code in my zul page, how can I define the  stuff in my viewModel?

If i assign with binded value

```
disabled="@load('vm.busy')"
```

to all components I want to disable during email sending, and substitute Clients showBusy and clearBusy with

```
busy = true; // Clients.showBusy(winFather.getModalWin(), "Please wait...");
...
busy = false; // Clients.clearBusy(winFather.getModalWin());
```

I got the same problem, the email is sending before zul components were disabled. It seems to be a sync problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> hi
>   i had same problem before , in my code you can see that I've override onClientInfo on my target component,so if you call this event , you can reach your goal.

```
@Listen("onClick = #addRejectDocumentBtn")
public void openWaiting() {
    Clients.showBusy(saleRejectMainPageWin,"please wait...");

    saleRejectMainPageWin.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLIENT_INFO, new EventListener<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {
            LongOperationExample();      <- here is my long operation                

            Clients.clearBusy(saleRejectMainPageWin);
        }
    });


    "Here you can call the event" 
    Events.echoEvent("onClientInfo", saleRejectMainPageWin, null);

}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for answer. However I'm using MVVM, so I can't apply your solution to my project.

Comment: @barracus hi again,i've changed my code for you and this new code have no dependency to MVC or MVVM . I've tested this code and it has exact functionality that  you need.

Comment: Thanks for help, it works fine. If you need alternatives I find a similar way to resolve it in [this example](https://gist.github.com/dennischen/2766642).